# How do I run code before user leaves the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onbeforeunload

Nothing I've tried does work. I need to run some code before the user leaves the page all:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   alert(1);
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   alert(2);
});

    window.addEventListener('unload', function(e) { alert(3); })
```

How am I supposed to do that nowadays? if matter, in the real application i'm using react and nextjs.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do when the user leaves the page. If you want to send information to your server side, then use a [Beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API). If you want to ask the user if they are sure they want to leave the page, then return a value from the event handler. If you want to do *anything* else, then it will not be possible. The unload event has been heavily restricted to prevent user-unfriendly or even malicious intent.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How can I use Beacon to archive that? my goal here is to call `navigator.sendBeacon()` before the user leaves the page but I can't find the proper event to do that[

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58732877/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for the help. I'll call `navigator.sendBeacon()` on `mouseout` event.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As an alternative to sending beacons (which my browser blocks by the way) you can catch the user as they move the mouse cursor out of the window and before they can kill the tab via...

```
window.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {

// do something here

});
```

Of course, the user may not necessarily kill the tab on leaving the window but there’s no harm in updating something when they do move away.

Comment: I'll rather use this one. unload and whatnot seems rather problematic.

Comment: Wise choice… beacons are often used maliciously and the paranoid community (myself included) block them vigorously.

Comment: I just saw browsers like brave seems to block those automatically

Comment: It's easy to close a tab without moving the mouse?!

Comment: Too bad... there are no perfect solutions.